# Websockets situation - on port 80 or 443, websocket message doesn't go through

Tags: http, websocket, jetty

i'm having a problem with my app, on a certain situation.

We have a java server with jetty webserver embedded, and an air app on the client side.

It is working properly but on a single situation of a certain customer.

They have a private network that is not administrated by them (and has little chances of being changed as request). So, the only port they allow are 80 and 443.

The communications between the server and the client are through websockets and http.

The "online" check is made through http and, then, we use websockets to notify the client in order to start communication between them.

The thing is, in this situation, the "online" state works properly and any communication send by the client (forced), as it goes through http, gets to the server but, when the server communicates with the client, using websockets, it doesn't work.

We are using wireshark to check the communications: On a working setup, when the client app starts, a websocket is shown on wireshark, on the server side (registering the client on the server). And, after that, websockets that are only used from server to the client, don't show also.

What can be the problem? The port 80? (the same happens with 443 on that network).
Can it be a proxy/firewall that are blocking ws:// messages?
I've read somewhere that wss:// (encripted websockets) would work?

Thanks for your help.

---

Edit, so, I tried with https and wss communication and the same thing happens.. no websocket is set between the client and server (registering the client on the server).

This situation is happening for http on the customer network. On my test network, it works on http/ws but not with https/wss..

Comment: It's difficult to say without examining the raw messages but I have lots of experience with proxies stripping headers required for the websocket handshake. Such problems are remedied by encrypting your traffic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many firewalls and gateways out "in the wild" that do not understand the whole WebSocket HTTP/1.1 GET -> UPGRADE -> WebSocket mechanism.

There are several broken firewall implementations will attempt to interpret the WebSocket framing as improper content for HTTP/1.1 (which is a bad reading of the HTTP/1.1 spec) and start to muck with it.

The types of firewalls that inspect/filter/analyze the request/response contents are the ones that seem most susceptible.

I would check that the hardware (or software) that they are using to firewall their network is both compliant and upgraded to support WebSocket RFC-6455.

Comment: I edited the mains post with new info.. on my test network is works with http/ws, but when trying with https/wss, the same happens, even with firewalls down..